# Ways to speed up IN queries under PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, performance

I have a query of the following form:

```
SELECT * FROM twitter_personas WHERE twitter_user_id IN ($1, $2, $3, ..., $25000)
```

The IN query has anywhere from 10 to 25000 values. The query runs for minutes at a time. I have a backlog of nearly 500,000 queries like this to run.

The twitter_user_id column is indexed. Any ideas on how I could speed this up?

```
# \d twitter_personas
                                    Table "public.twitter_personas"
      Column      |          Type          |                         Modifiers                          
------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------
 persona_id       | uuid                   | not null
 twitter_user_id  | bigint                 | 
 screen_name      | character varying(40)  | not null
 avatar_url       | text                   | 
 hashval          | integer                | not null default nextval('personas_hashval_seq'::regclass)
Indexes:
    "twitter_personas_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (persona_id)
    "index_twitter_personas_on_screen_name" UNIQUE, btree (screen_name)
    "index_twitter_personas_on_screen_name_persona_id" btree (screen_name, persona_id)
    "index_twitter_personas_twitter_user_id" btree (twitter_user_id) WHERE twitter_user_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Where do these long lists of id's come from? Are they stored/calculated outside of the database?

Comment: The IDs are returned from Twitter as the list of followers a person has.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IN() using many parameters will result in many cases in a sequential table scan. That might be slow, depending on table size and speed of your system.

Create a temporary table with all your variables and join on this table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t AS 
  SELECT * FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3)) x(twitter_user_id);

SELECT 
  twitter_personas.* 
FROM twitter_personas 
  JOIN t USING(twitter_user_id);
```

Use EXPLAIN to see the difference between the queryplans.

Comment: +1 for your ingenuity. I have a question though: Would a LEFT OUTER JOIN and RIGHT OUTER JOIN produce different query plans, or would there be no significant differenece ???

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA: You have to check the results from EXPLAIN, but a LEFT or RIGHT join will result in different results than the current IN() or INNER JOIN. Maybe it's also possible to solve this performance problem using a Common Table Expression, but I didn't check it with many values nor a prepared statement.

Comment: I'll try the temporary table route.

Comment: A [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) with the same `VALUE` row constructor will work just as well. Even faster - it is basically a temporary table, just with less overhead.

Comment: A CTE is better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use ANY.

```
 SELECT * FROM twitter_personas 
 WHERE twitter_user_id ANY (VALUES  ($1), ($2), ($3), ..., ($25000))
```

I ran a query with 1000 parameters and it took 4 minutes using IN and 1 second using ANY. You can also use ANY ARRAY Rather than ANY VALUES but from my reading this is slower than ANY VALUES.